# two or more nested RelativeLayout 

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to ask, working with two or more nested RelativeLayout.
First code looks like picture 1, When I add `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` in second RelativeLayout, this looks like picture 2. I want to align text right to second RelativeLayout. Where is my fault?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/testRL">
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/testRotateLL"
                android:background="@drawable/picture_border_offer_first_page">
                <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="7000TL"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:id="@+id/amountLayoutTV" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Picture 1:

[image: Picture 1]

And I add `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/testRL">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/testRotateLL"
            android:background="@drawable/picture_border_offer_first_page">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7000TL"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:id="@+id/amountLayoutTV" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Picture 2:

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: try to add to `TextView` `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Comment: worst-case scenario: Add `ImageView` before `TextView` instead of `android:background="@drawable/picture_border_offer_first_page"`. They will overlay

Comment: @first I tried alightTop, its same.

Comment: @second. maybe, I can do it adding an imageview, but this is not my questions answer...  (I will try)

Comment: I think the problem is in the first `RelativeLayout`. It's `layout_width` should be `fill_parent`!

Comment: I had the same problem with a nested layout, took me several hours to find what causes it. Had to do with LinearLayouts and avoiding aligning with parent... there is a flaw somewhere in Android code I believe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is unanswered. when I updated ADT version, this problem solved. There was a bug, I think.

I suggest you to check version of ADT sometimes...

Comment: also another tip, don't always update your ADT version!
because newer versions come with newer bugs! you should always test the adt on another eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In the first RelativeLayout you have:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You probably want:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```